# What function is called when Alt-Enter is pressed?

Tags: c++, windows, directx-11

I have a game app that has the ability to go fullscreen and back to windowed when Alt-Enter is pressed. However, when it goes fullscreen, I get the following warning from DirectX:

`DXGI Warning: IDXGISwapChain::Present: Fullscreen presentation inefficiencies incurred due to application not using IDXGISwapChain::ResizeBuffers appropriately, specifying a DXGI_MODE_DESC not available in IDXGIOutput::GetDisplayModeList, or not using DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH.`

I've already ruled out the second two possibilities through testing, so I know the only reasons left for the warning to pop up are either IDXGISwapChain::ResizeBuffers isn't being used right, or Windows is just bugged. Since I can't debug the 2nd possibility, I'm sticking with the ResizeBuffers problem. To debug this, I want to look at what happens when Alt-Enter is pressed going from windowed to fullscreen. However, the app does not seem to be calling my ResizeDXGIBuffers method; in fact, it seems that Alt-Enter is embedded into windows or DirectX somewhere, and I don't know how to find the chain of function calls that go off when it is pressed. EDIT: When my method is put in the WM_ACTIVATEAPP handler, it is called, but this is not what i meant. If i take it out of that message handler, the window STILL goes to fullscreen, even though I am not calling any functions to make the window fullscreen myself. So Alt+Enter must be automatically calling some internal function to do this.

So that is my question: Does anyone know what function is called by windows and/or DirectX 11 when Alt-Enter is pressed?

EDIT: As the tags for this question say, I am using DirectX 11 on a Windows machine. Specifically, Windows 7 64-bit.

EDIT 2: I now completely eat the Alt+Enter keystroke and manually store the state of Alt+Enter being pressed so that I know for certain only my code is being called. The warning I spoke of above persists, however. I am following the [MSDN best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as well, so I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Full_Screen_Issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the MSDN best practices page and re-working my code to reflect all of the practices described, the warning has disappeared. I hope this helps anyone else that has the same problem.

Also, thanks to Hans Passant for the link. I already fixed it by the time you posted it, but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try handling the [`WM_ACTIVATEAPP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.

I do not know which framework you use to create your windows, so I can't tell how to concretely handle this message.

Comment: sorry, this is not what i am looking for. I already handle that message. There is definitely an embedded call that resizes my window without me doing it manually.